# Valley-filling optimization in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

i'm trying to simulate a distributed scheduler for ev (electric vehicle) charging. the desired behavior would shave peaks and fill valley, in other words minimize the peak-to-average ratio of the electric load on a test grid. ( such as in this paper: web.eecs.umich.edu/~hiskens/publications/1940.pdf  )

Picture of wanted result:

[image: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/13055/Capture.PNG]

So, basically, what I'm doing is this:

- send to each user the aggregate load of the rest of the grid
- initialize the charge scheduling vector randomly, this will be the starting point x0 of the IPM optimization
- optimize: i want to minimize the peak-to-average ratio, or equivalently, the cost (quadratic fcn) of the supplied energy

The constraints are the following:

- The sum of the charges scheduled between now and the departure moment of the vehicle is equal to the energy requirement (first line of Aeq)
- Past scheduling cannot be changed (so it's equal to past load, **ecs.ev_load** ), scheduling post-departure must be zero ( **I** , the rest of Aeq matrix)
- lower bound of energy consumption is zero
- upper bound is a given parameter, **ecs.max_load**

  ```
  x0=ecs.schedule;
  I=eye(ecs.timeslots);
  I(ecs.currenttime:ecs.ev.departure,:)=[];
  Aeq=[zeros(1,ecs.currenttime-1) -1*ones(1,ecs.ev.departure-ecs.currenttime+1) zeros(1,ecs.timeslots-ecs.ev.departure);I];
  beq=[-1*ecs.ev.requested_chg*ecs.nslotsperhour;ecs.ev_load;zeros(ecs.timeslots-ecs.ev.departure,1)];
  A=[];
  b=[];
  nonlcon=[];
  lb=zeros(ecs.timeslots,1);
  ub=ecs.max_load*ones(ecs.timeslots,1);
  options = optimoptions('fmincon','Algorithm','interior-point','MaxFunEvals',30000);
  ```

The objective function **par** at each ev sums

- **x**: the scheduled load of the vehicle (the optimization variable)
- **other_loads**: the *future* behavior of every non-ev load (unrealistic), the loads of the rest of ev schedules

  ```
  other_loads=ecs.game_l;    %l_n (all schedules in the grid, mine included)
  other_loads(:,ecs.id)=[];  %l_-n (removed my own schedule)
  schedule = fmincon(@par,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,options);


  function f=par(x)
      tot=sum([x other_loads],2);
      f=max(tot)/mean(tot);
  end
  ```

Picture of what I'm getting:

[image]

Here's my problem: the optimization doesn't work. I keep tinkering with the code, but I always get (almost) the same result, where the valleys aren't filled at all, and the behaviour is almost constant. I verified by debugging that the content of the variables is correct, maybe I'm doing something wrong with the optimizer?
Thanks in advance